# Power distribution in a defocused focal plane

Tags: optics, geometric-optics

Given an optical system of focal length $EFL$ and f number $f/n$, if the focal plane is defocused in a way that the defocused plane distance from the focused plane is $d$, assuming we have a point source at $\infty$ and the incident power on the optical system is $P_0$, what is the power distribution of the power on the new defocused plane?
Thanks

Comment: You are probably searching for the exact solution of the Fresnel diffraction, which is related also to fractional Fourier transform. The exact pattern depends on the size and shape of your optical system aperture.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a problem in Fresnel diffraction.  There is no closed-form solution, as there is for the PSF (point spread function) in the focal plane.  There is an exact solution in terms of an integral.  The details and the integral, along with series approximations good for small values of defocus  can be found in Chapter 9 of Born and Wolf.   Born and Wolf also presents series solutions for aberrated systems.

More recently, series solutions have been found that converge more quickly, and that are good for larger values of defocus and aberrations.  These solutions are called the Extended Nijboer-Zernike series.    Lots and lots of details can be found at [this web site](http://www.nijboerzernike.nl/).

There are also solutions using Fourier transforms, and Fresnel transforms, and even direct integration solutions. Which approach you use depends on your needs.

All of them are way too long and complicated to present here.